# Cant force Calendar to change its time

Tags: android, parsing, calendar, simpledateformat

Im trying to get the current date and set the time on 20:00
I'm able to get it nu my code doesnt set the time, but also no errors. If i debug it hours is stille the current time. can you guys help me ?

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String monthS = toString().valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    String dayS = toString().valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  //  int hourI = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  //  int minI = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    String yearS = toString().valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));






    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm yyyy");
    try
    {
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(monthS + " " + dayS + " " + "20:00" + yearS));

    } catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long currentMil = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    int hourI = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    while (hourI <19)
    {
        currentMil = currentMil + ONE_HOUR;
        hourI ++;
    }
    System.out.println(currentMil);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: The hour is now changed, thnx. only one problem the time (milliseconds sinds 1970) arent changed. Is there a way to also change those

Comment: try cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Comment: also try cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Comment: Close but not exactly what I'm looking  for. I want to know how many milisec has passed sinds 1970 if its 20:00. at the moment its 14:17 and the milisec, or the time variable of Calendar, is1446729472000 now in cal i changed hour to 20:00 but the milisecond stay at 1446729472000 instead of how many it would be if it is 20:00

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `MMM` try `M` if months are X (1) or `MM` if months are XX (01).

`MMM` stands for `Jan...Dec`